# resteasy+wildfly+maven throwing class not found on rest service implementation

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jboss

i am working on mkyong [mkyong site for implementing resteasy](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/)

while implementing it i came across error which is so weird 
[image: project structure and messageRestservice.java file]

messageApplciation.java

```
package com.mkyong.rest;
 import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import com.mkyong.rest.MessageRestService;
public class MessageApplication extends Application {
private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public MessageApplication() {
    singletons.add(new MessageRestService());
}
@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
}
```

web.xml file

```
 <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest.MessageApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mkyong.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>RESTfulExample</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>RESTfulExample Maven Webapp</name>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>RESTfulExample</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>sam</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.Final</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.Final</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>

    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

error:
[image]

I have deployed app in Jboss wildfly after maven build.

Observations:
while doing mvn compile war:war i found see 0 sources are compiled, may be it is because some issue with pom.

i have been working on this from past 2 days still didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Source causes this removing it made it work